# Browser ask me to download php file

Tags: php, file, browser, download

I am a new guy in web programming who still learning new stuff.

I am creating a web form that consist of one INPUT. I connected the form in the HTML file to the php file. I am using a localhost MAMP that I recently installed on my MacBook.

**The Problem :** When I open the HTML file on a webpage and type something on the input box and hit submit, the browser ask me to download the php file rather processing it.

I don’t think the problem is related to mysql or apache since when I run the MAMP it give me green signs next to the apache and mysql.

Do anyone know how I can fix this problem and the let the php file open and transfer inputs to the database?

Comment: looks to me you didn't setup php correctly!

Comment: What are the HTTP headers being sent when you submit the form?

Comment: maybe the php file doesn't have execute permission? not sure this matters, as the file should just be read, but perhaps it's worth checking too...

Comment: wheres your code? did you just like the file to your html or are you processing it in any way?

Comment: @mingos: PHP scripts don't need execute permissions. They're not executables. At most it just has to be readable by the webserver.

Comment: @Marc B: yeah, that's what I thought...

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to make sure that Apache has been told that .php files should be treated as PHP scripts. That means one of the following:

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so    # on windows, this'd be a .dll instead
AddHandler php5-script php
```

and/or

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php php
```

in your httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

open your file from virtual web-server, not filesystem.
you have to type something like

```
http://localhost/form.html
```

in your browser's address bar

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked out http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/faq.html#q8 ?

Maybe you didn't put your site into the folder "htdocs"?
PHP won't be parsed unless it is located in that folder or a subfolder.

That would explain the fact that your browser downloads the php file instead of getting the parsed php from apache.

Answer (score 0):

This error is not only about php but general. The file that the browser suggets to down load is simply the script name, php or not.