# Enabling .so extension causes code to be downloaded rather than run

Tags: php, lamp, php-extension

I'm trying to enable a PHP extension, but whenever I un-comment any extensions in my `php.ini` file it causes the code from a file to be downloaded whenever I try to run it in a browser.

---

**EDIT**

I've added

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/sdo.so
AddHandler php5-script php
AddType application/x-httpd-php php
```

To the `httpd.conf` file but it is still not working.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477603/browser-ask-me-to-download-php-file

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to explain what he meant by this line

`AddHandler php5-script php` 

As I'm not sure what to add into the httpd,conf file

Comment: have you compiled apache separately? what distro you are using and how have you set-up lamp and have you setup VirtualHost? a less resistance path would be [XAMPP for GNU/Linux](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html)

Comment: Installed Xampp on Fedora, I'm getting a new error when trying to start XAMPP:
`undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init`

Comment: check for directory permissions..set them 755..else better would be to reinstall XAMPP..

Comment: set the sdo.so file to 755 or is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a PHP extension, which I assume is the [Service Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sdo.php) extension, then you're simply not enabling it correctly.

Extensions in PHP are enabled by editing `php.ini` and adding a line like so:

```
extension=sdo.so
```

What you're doing right now is loading the SDO extension as the `php5_module`, causing an invalid or inexistent Apache module to handle PHP files.

**You don't have to edit any Apache configuration files to enable a PHP extension.**