# PHP: browser just downloads the file instead of reproducing it

Tags: php, linux, download

I'm using Linux Mint, Apache2 and PHP5. My Web IDE is Aptana Studio 3.

When I try to run my PHP file, the browser, instead of reproducing the content of the PHP

```
 <?php echo "hello" ?>
```

it just downloads the file, not even showing it's content on the screen.

I'm new to PHP so I would like to have a hand here. Why is this happening and how should I solve it?
Thank you for your time

Comment: Tell Apache how to handle php files.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477603/browser-ask-me-to-download-php-file)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't got the PHP extension enabled in Apache or the module loaded.

Have a look in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` and check for a symlink to `../mods-available/php.load` (or something similar)

That's usually all you need to do on apache2 to enable the module.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo "hello" ?>`

should be replaced by:

`<?php echo "hello"; ?>`

But this won't solve your question. Your php file will be downloaded by the browser as apache is not working in the right way. As we can't see how you did set it up we won't be able to solve your question.. Can you provide us with some more information? PHP extension not installed?