# php downloaded instead of viewing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I am a beginner of web development and just started to learn about a month

intro:

I  recently come across SQL injection and decided to look it up. After summarizing it, I tried to upgrade my cpanel php version from 5.3 to 5.4 due to PDO support. So I was messing around with `.htaccess` file and after I uploaded my new `.htaccess` file I can no longer view my php page again. I don't remember what codes did I put.....

Question: What should I do to undo my stupidity?

Tried solution:

1. I emptied my .htaccess file and still the same result
2. I loaded up codes in .htaccess file with

   > LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
   >
   > AddHandler php5-script php
   >
   > AddType application/x-httpd-php php

   (from [Browser ask me to download php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477603/browser-ask-me-to-download-php-file))
   and still the same result
3. Somewhere I have read to change the php file name will undo the damage, It works. But I like my original php file name, so I tried rename back to the original file name and the problem happens again

Sorry for my bad English practice

Update:
I was browsing my website again, and somehow got into an error saying 
500 - Internal Server Error
, so I decided to delete all my files in public_html file. Then,I re-upload all my web file again and suddenly it all worked. Did not download php file again.

Thanks for everyone who spends time on looking at my problem. I apologize to all the contributor.

The file name on both regist and register have a extension name of .php

Comment: Do you have access to shell on that server?

Comment: `I have read to change the php file name will undo the damage, It works` - what filename _doesn't_ work? You're maybe looking at your own browser cache.

Comment: I saw SSH/Shell access but I don't know how to deal with it. "Manage SSH Keys" is the only option in that page...

Comment: originally was register, I rename it to regist to test if that method was working

Comment: you need `SetHandler` http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php  `<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: What was the FULL filename of your file. Especially the extension is important. It should be `.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being asked to download the file because the server no longer recognizes the file as something it needs to process.

I'm not sure why you would need all the PHP declarations in your `.htaccess` file (especially `LoadModule`). Normally those are stored in config files (files like `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`). Here's what the default on my box looks like (this is for Apache so YMMV)

```
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
#<IfModule prefork.c>
<IfModule !worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
#AddHandler php5-script .php
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

#
# Uncomment the following line to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: the .htaccess file was my issue. deleting it solved the problem.
I had this issue when I moved from one server provider (who neede this .htaccess file to work) to another provider (who didn't need this file to work)